# Reading a zip file using JSZIP library

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read a zip file in my JavaScript.

```
 function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    console.log("name "+files.name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var zip = new JSZip(evt.target.result);
    for( var entryName in zip.files){
        console.log("name of files "+entryName.name);           
    }
 }

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

https://github.com/Stuk/jszip

https://jsfiddle.net/3n4ndw86/1/

That's what I wrote so far, but I don't get the name of the files in the console

Comment: what is `filesInput` ? it's never defined in the code you gave

Comment: I just modified my code I'm using the library JSZip to read my zip file

Comment: A zip archive is a blob – when you throw it in to a datafield of type blob…

Comment: thank you for you answer actually I'm not getting this error anymore I have modified my code now I'm using the JSZip library but still I can't read the zip file to get the files names

Comment: if you get undefined - what do you get if you change your log line to `console.log("name of files " + entryName);` ??

Comment: I am not taking the time to write a full answer, but here's a working example of code I wrote recently. I hope this gives you the clues you need: https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/main/src/components/RezLoader.vue